# KernelOops when using printk() inside kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm implementing a linux module to use as a frequency governor. I'm new to linux module development, so I'm trying to understand the governors already implemented. The following code is based on the performance governor.

```
#include <linux/cpufreq.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static void cpufreq_gov_performance_limits(struct cpufreq_policy *policy)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "DEBUG: Frequency set to 1500 MHz.\n");
    __cpufreq_driver_target(policy, 1500000, CPUFREQ_RELATION_H);
}

static struct cpufreq_governor cpufreq_gov_performance = {
    .name       = "mtest",
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
    .limits     = cpufreq_gov_performance_limits,
};

static int __init cpufreq_gov_performance_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "DEBUG: Governor inserted.\n");
    return cpufreq_register_governor(&cpufreq_gov_performance);
}

static void __exit cpufreq_gov_performance_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "DEBUG: Governor released.\n");
    cpufreq_unregister_governor(&cpufreq_gov_performance);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(cpufreq_gov_performance_init);
module_exit(cpufreq_gov_performance_exit);
```

When I load the module without the `printk()`, the governor works without errors. But when using `printk()`, I get a KernelOops when removing the module (using `rmmod`).

This is the message logged in the `/var/crash` directory. In this test, I've set 2 cpu's from `ondemand` to my custom governor and returning to `ondemand`, then removed the module:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Sun May  6 22:54:48 2018
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 DEBUG: Governor inserted.
 DEBUG: Frequency set to 1500 MHz.
 DEBUG: Frequency set to 1500 MHz.
 DEBUG: Governor released.

Package: linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic 4.15.0-20.21
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64
```

What could be happening?

Comment: Is that everything what you have got in logs? Don't you have any calltrace in there? It there is any - show it us.